# CQL generates two columns per value?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am wondering why is Cassandra creating two columns when I add a cell with CQL?

This is my schema:

```
DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS tsdb;

CREATE KEYSPACE tsdb WITH replication =
{
    'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
    'replication_factor' : 3
};

USE tsdb;

CREATE TABLE datapoints (
    tsid int,
    key text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (tsid, key)
);

INSERT INTO datapoints (tsid, key, value) 
VALUES (
    1,
    'foo',
    0x012345
);

INSERT INTO datapoints (tsid, key, value) 
VALUES (
    2,
    'foo',
    0x500000
);
```

Querying it in CQLSH looks good:

```
cqlsh:tsdb> SELECT * FROM datapoints;

 tsid | key | value
------+-----+----------
    1 | foo | 0x012345
    2 | foo | 0x500000

(2 rows)
```

but when I list the rows via cassandra-cli I get two columns per row:

```
[default@tsdb] list datapoints;
Using default limit of 100
Using default cell limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 1
=> (name=foo:, value=, timestamp=1405353603216000)
=> (name=foo:value, value=012345, timestamp=1405353603216000)
-------------------
RowKey: 2
=> (name=foo:, value=, timestamp=1405353603220000)
=> (name=foo:value, value=500000, timestamp=1405353603220000)

2 Rows Returned.
Elapsed time: 6.9 msec(s).
```

I was expecting to get something like:

```
-------------------
RowKey: 1
=> (name=foo:value, value=012345, timestamp=1405353603216000)
-------------------
RowKey: 2
=> (name=foo:value, value=500000, timestamp=1405353603220000)

2 Rows Returned.
```

Why does CQL create columns with the name "foo:" and an empty value? What are these good for?

Thank you!

Best,
Malte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Understanding How CQL3 Maps to Cassandra’s Internal Data Structure](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/)

Thanks to John Berryman for the depth explanation of CQL mapping under the hood.